# Absolute and Relative positioning for a container

Tags: css, css-position

```
#container {

            background-color: grey;
            top: 40px;
            left: 50px;
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            position: absolute;
            border: 2px solid black;
            }
```

I have a single div tag in the body with this id. Nothing else. Lets say the top-left vertex of this container displays in the browser at location x,y. Now when I change the position property to relative, ironically it displays at a location ~(x+10, y+10). Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you, by any chance, remove the default margin from the `body`? It's likely the default margin applied by most browsers.

Try adding this:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5TZBf/

Comment: Yes! That solves it! I'm just wondering what might have caused it. In no ways had I altered the body tag in any way. But thanks anyways, just wanted to confirm what the default behaviour should be.

Comment: Most, if not all, browsers have a default "stylesheet" where the `body` usually has a margin of 10 applied on all sides which explains your issue. You need to explicitly override those default values by adding a definition in your stylesheet as suggested; commonly known as a CSS Reset (of which there are plenty available for free on the web).

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the default margins on the page a simple reset can be done. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Last1Here/qaAnk/)

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
```